# Google Places Autocomplete suggestions with Unit No/Subpremise is not coming in the response array

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using Google places API to auto-complete addresses using javascript

When I type the unit number and street number of address in the input box it shows the results in suggestion drop-down but when I select the address the listener for action 'place_changed' event don't have any address with address_component with type 'subpremise' even the formatted_address property don't have the unit number in it.Though it does contain other details from 'street number','city','country' etc

For example : If I type "1403/648 Bourke Street" with a country restriction to Australia. It shows me 5 results in the dropdown with first one as "1403/648 Bourke street, Melbourne,Australia" but when I select this option all I get in the place_change event listener is "648 Bourke street, Melbourne, Australia"

This issue is intermittent though, it works for some unit addresses but fail for other.Any suggestion will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: I don't know the reason for this behavior, you can use google places by passing lat lon that you received, maybe the object that you will get from there will contain more data.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I am having the same issue. Also Australia units, not sure if that is something specific to the country. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to me like Google is validating that the address is real (well atleast real when they last updated their places database - I guess with government records). The problem is that subdivisions are happening all the time where new "subpremise" addresses are created, and a look up on these seems to be br0ken more often. It's strange that they allow a "non-valid" address as an autocomplete suggestion but then limit the result.

A look up on the Sydney address below will return "subpremise" and "street_number"

"9/321 Pitt Street, Sydney, New South Wales, Australia"

Where the Melbourne address below only gets as accurate as "route"

"2/321 Pitt Street, Brunswick, Victoria, Australia"

The biggest problem is that the result doesn't return the unit or street number anywhere in the reply.

I have hacked together the following JS to compare the user-entered address with the returned result. If the "numbers" are missing, they are added. You can customise as you need to fit with your code.

```
if (addressType == 'route') {
    var regex = RegExp('^(.*)'+GPLACESSTREET.split(' ',1)[0]), // get all the user entered values before a match with the first word from the Google result
        result = regex.exec(INPUTFEILD.value);

    if ( Array.isArray(result) ) {
        FULLSTREETADDRESS = result[1]+''+GPLACESSTREET; // add the street name to the user-entered unit & street number
    }
}
```

Comment: Places Autocomplete API is designed to allow users to type in whatever they want and return an address that matches it best, based on base map data. For a wide range of reasons, subpremise-level details are not always available, and so they are seldom returned. Your workaround of recovering "numbers" from user input is probably the best practical option.

Answer (score 11):

The Places Autocomplete API is not designed to support 'subpremise' results. This was reported and answered some time ago in the public issue tracker at https://issuetracker.google.com/35830389

Australian addresses for subpremise results look "close enough" to those of street_address/premise results (they start with mostly digits). This is currently resulting in Place Autocomplete returning what may look like a subpremise result, however note that the type is still "route":

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=9/321%20Pitt%20Street,%20Sydney

```
description: "9/321 Pitt Street, Sydney NSW, Australia",
place_id: "Eig5LzMyMSBQaXR0IFN0cmVldCwgU3lkbmV5IE5TVywgQXVzdHJhbGlh",
types: ["route","geocode",],
```

Place Details (and Geocoding) requests with this place_id will in fact find the correct subpremise result:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=Eig5LzMyMSBQaXR0IFN0cmVldCwgU3lkbmV5IE5TVywgQXVzdHJhbGlh

```
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "9",
            "short_name" : "9",
            "types" : [ "subpremise" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "321",
            "short_name" : "321",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
      ...
      "formatted_address" : "9/321 Pitt St, Sydney NSW 2000, Australia",
      "types" : [ "subpremise" ],
```

However, this is not guaranteed to work for all subpremise queries, or even for this particular one in the long term.

A more reliable approach would be to use the Geocoding API to search for the prediction's "description":

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=9%2F321%20Pitt%20St%2C%20Sydney%20NSW%202000%2C%20Australia

```
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "9",
               "short_name" : "9",
               "types" : [ "subpremise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "321",
               "short_name" : "321",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            ...
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "9/321 Pitt St, Sydney NSW 2000, Australia",
         "place_id" : "Eik5LzMyMSBQaXR0IFN0LCBTeWRuZXkgTlNXIDIwMDAsIEF1c3RyYWxpYSIdGhsKFgoUChIJkyPU0z2uEmsR-pmiK6UvZUASATk",
         "types" : [ "subpremise" ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Google doesn't support it, but you cant stop customers doing it!

Here is a complete function inspired by @MountainAsh's & @Randell's code:

```
/* Add the unit number (+ fix the street number) if required.
 *
 * Idea from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936689/google-places-autocomplete-suggestions-with-unit-no-subpremise-is-not-coming-in
 *
 * Test cases:
 * 9/321 Pitt Street, Sydney, New South Wales, Australia <-- Google throws away the unit number
 * 2/321 Pitt Street, Brunswick, Victoria, Australia <-- Google says street number = 2
 * 1b/123 Clayton Road, Clayton, Victoria, Australia <-- Google says street number = 1
 */
function autofillUnitNumber(txtAutocomplete, txtUnitNumber, txtStreetNumber, txtStreetName) {
    var regex = RegExp("^(.*?)\/(.*?) " + txtStreetName.value); // get all the user entered values before a match with the street name; group #1 = unit number, group #2 = street number
    var results = regex.exec(txtAutocomplete.value);

    if (Array.isArray(results)) { // it was in unit number/street number format
        var unitNumber = results[1]; // group #1 
        var streetNumber = results[2]; // group #2

        txtUnitNumber.value = unitNumber;
        txtStreetNumber.value = streetNumber;
    }
}
```

Just call it after you have used Google autocomplete to autofill your other form fields eg:

```
autofillUnitNumber(
    document.getElementById("txtAutocomplete"),
    document.getElementById("txtUnitNumber"),
    document.getElementById("txtStreetNumber"),
    document.getElementById("txtStreetName"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I just wanted to collect the Unit number and prepend it to the Street Number, my solution is:

```js
const place = this.AutoComplete.getPlace();
if (isNullOrUndefined(place)) return;

const parts = place.address_components;
const getAddressPart = part => {
  const found = parts.find(p => p.types.indexOf(part) > -1);
  if (found) {
    return found.long_name;
  }

  return null;
};

const address = this.Input.current.value; // input[text] value
let streetNumber = getAddressPart("street_number");

// Regex Match associated
if (streetNumber) {
  const regex = RegExp(`[^\\s,]*(${streetNumber})[^\\s,]*`);
  const foundStreetNumber = regex.exec(address);
  streetNumber = foundStreetNumber[0];
}

const Address = {
  FullAddress: address,
  StreetNumber: streetNumber,
  Street: getAddressPart("route"),
  Suburb: getAddressPart("sublocality"),
  City: getAddressPart("locality"),
  Country: getAddressPart("country"),
  PostCode: getAddressPart("postal_code")
};
```

This will improve the street number data from the Google Places API, catering for addresses such as:

**4/33 Mokoia Rd, Birkenhead, Auckland 0626, New Zealand**

**Proletarska ulica 3/25, Kidričevo, Slovenia** (An address might not have the Street Number first).

It will also not do any work if there is no street number, and the value will be the same if there is no unit number.

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification from @MountainAsh's code:

```
if (addressType == 'route') {
  var regex = RegExp('^(.*?)'+GPLACESSTREET.split(' ',1)[0]), // get all the user entered values before a match with the first word from the Google result
  result = regex.exec(INPUTFEILD.value);

  if ( Array.isArray(result) ) {
    FULLSTREETADDRESS = result[1]+''+GPLACESSTREET; // add the street name to the user-entered unit & street number
  }
}
```

Notice the additional **?** in **RegExp**, which makes the search non-greedy to cover cases where the Street Name starts with the same Suburb name (e.g. 123 Clayton Rd, Clayton).