# Google Place API Unit Number not fetching

Tags: google-places-api

Google Place API not fetching the Unit number for the specific address.[image]

```
Example: 3/12 Selwyn Avenue Elwood, 3184, Mel, VIC
```

But some addresses it's fetching the unit number properly.[image: 15/25 Batlow Street, Heckenberg NSW, Australia]

```
Example: 15/25 Batlow Street, Heckenberg NSW, Australia
```

Here **subpremise** is the unit number in the response

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar issue reported on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936689/google-places-autocomplete-suggestions-with-unit-no-subpremise-is-not-coming-in).

As per the [support issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830389#comment3):

> Support for subpremise elements (apt. / suite) is limited. Place
>   Autocomplete is not intended to support these universally.
>
> Geocoding API will find these places, and return subpremise elements
>   in address_components:

so your mileage may vary.